# Step/Tasklet executed always even if job fails

Tags: spring-batch

I designed a tasklet which sends a mail based on reading an "status" execution context param I customly store.

```
|STEP 1| - |STEP 2| - |STEP 3| - |STEP 4| (Happy Path)
     |        |          |
 On fail, interrupt flow and go starightforward into STEP 4 (Mail Sender)
```

Any step on the flow must be forwarded to that tasklet in case something fails, which implies I must deal with JobConfiguration flows. Somehow I feel like my design is a bit clumsy, but the alternative does not convince me either.

Is the aforementioned approach preferable to having all this code as a side-effect on each step by means of ExecutionListeners + MailService?

Is there a cleaner alternative approach? What does spring-batch experts usually do?

Comment: Why the close vote? Any explanation is appreciated

Comment: I voted to close your question with reason "Needs details or clarity" because it's first version (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61324601/1) was not clear to me. But I see you edited it with more details, so that's a good first step. When you say `but the alternative does not convince me either.` Which alternative are you referring to? I don't see any alternative described in your question. It's important to share your code to be able to help you. Have you tried to use a conditional flow https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#conditionalFlow ?

Comment: Sorry for my bad grammar. The alternative, the one I came up with, is explained in next line (step executionlisteners + mailservice). But maybe there is a better one

Comment: No worries. I see nothing wrong with this approach. If the requirement is to execute 3 steps in sequence and short-circuit some of them in case of failure, then you have to implement it that way. Now how to implement that flow is an implementation details, and with Spring Batch, you can do that with a conditional flow. The link I shared shows many examples, if you can't achieve what you want, please share your code and I will try to help.